# c# datetime format using singleline

Tags: c#, datetime

Any easy way to get the the date in this (european) format?

day/month/year hour/minute/sec

I need the date with a space between year and hour.
If possible without saving it into a string, because I draw it on images as a timestamp.

Comment: What do you mean "Without saving to a string"? You can format a date into that string, but there will always be a string involved.

Comment: `Tahul Singh` I think that the `OP` may be wanting to use `string.Format()` function there are also that's a rather strange format to have Timestamp values separated by `/` anyway `Dehner` do a simple google search on `Formatting Dates [DateTime format](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) also `dehner` update the question and show us an exact example of what the european format looks like

Comment: What is "European format"? 11/Avr/2014? 11/Apr/2014? 11/huhtikuu/2014? Have you considered using `CultureInfo`?

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the date and time as a string that you can draw on images:

```
datetimeObject.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH/mm/ss");
```

(Edited due to comment that slashes are required.)

Comment: Your colons should be slashes according to the format in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Using your format, you can try `DateTime.Now.ToString("parameters")`. For example:

```
// Uppercase "MM" for month, lower-case for minutes.
// Uppercase "HH" denotes 24-hour time format. Lower-case is 12-hour time.
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH/mm/ss");
```

You can call that any time, anywhere, any place, without "saving it to a string." It will simply return a string.

I hope this helps!